# I need to solve this $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{n}{2^i}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How Can I bound this:
$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{n}{2^i} =?$
I think it is $O(n)$ but I am not sure and I do not know how to get there.

Comment: it's just a geometric series

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n}{2^i} = n \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^i}$.

Comment: Or, by inspection, $n \le S_n \le 2n$, and $S_n$ is thus $O(n)$.

Comment: I need more explanations please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple geometric series,as you've been told in the hints so review geometric series' definition  and it should be solved easily then .[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula][1]

Comment: Many thanks to all of you!